# Corsair H80i with Intel Core i7 4770K?

Tags: computer-building, cpu-cooler

Is the Corsair H80i CPU cooler compatible with an Intel Core i7 4770K?

On the product page of the Corsair H80i it says that it supports Intel LGA 1155, 1156, 1366, and 2011. The Intel Core i7 4770K is an LGA1150. Does that mean that I can't use the H80i for this CPU?

If I can't use the H80i, can you recommend a compatible CPU cooler from Corsair? (only 1-fan radiator)

Comment: We don't do product recomendations here at Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

The H80i seems to be discontinued, and it's not listed on the [Hydro-Series products page](http://www.corsair.com/en-ca/cpu-coolers/hydro-series) anymore.

The H100i is still available and it says it supports the LGA1150 specifically.

> Compatibility
>   •Intel™ LGA **1150**, 1155, 1156, 1366, and 2011.

All their current ones seem to support that socket.

My guess would be the H80i will work as well, as the sockets are basically the same, but sight-unseen I'd go for one that specifically claims compatibility, and that's current.

Comment: 1: Are you saying that the H80i will work? 2: I cant use the H100i, beacause it is more that 1-fan radiator

Comment: btw the H80i is actually in the bottom of the hydro-series page :) There is even a image of it and the H100i in the header

Comment: @user2372837 - Actually its not.  The H40 is the bottom of the series.

Comment: Their current page is linked in my answer, the H80 and below are NOT listed anywhere.  Just because the old page still exists on their server doesn't mean it's accurate. :)

Answer (score 0):

A LGA1155 heatsink can be installed on a LGA1150 motherboards. Nothing has changed in that regard since the 1156 socket was released.

I am pretty sure there was evidence on the Corsair website that indicates this heatsink actually does support the LGA 1150 socket.  Since the product your asking about has been discontinued its hard to actually know what information Corasair had posted.

[Amazon's Questions and Answers](http://www.amazon.com/Corsair-Series-Extreme-Performance-Liquid/forum/FxF5Y7TMIYTZBJ/-/1/ref=cm_cd_dp_aar_ql?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B009ZN03AA&cdSort=best) indicates it does

The layout of the pins used to secure the heatsink has not changed since Sandybridge.  The corsponding Intel Extreme sockets since the release of Sandybridge also have not been changed.